# PowerShell Code if statement failure

Tags: powershell, if-statement, installation, uninstallation

I have an interesting situation going on where an agent was installed and it communicates back to the server. This agent is now EOL and support with the vendor was not renewed. Many of our agents are no longer communicating back to the server because its on stuck calling back to our DMZ network where the server was decommissioned. The agent has a tamper protection with password and the old admin doesn't know the password.

What I found we can do is on these servers, install the agent again and then the appliance that is on our inside network change the password to whatever, for my case I did blank.

To make things worse the agent is installed in either `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)` and in some cases it's installed twice on the same server.

That's the background of the script I'm trying to develop. My idea was to download the agent from the appliance, detect the architecture and run the install then run an uninstall and loop it for each `Program Files` and/or `Program Files(x86)`. I have it working OK, but it's not removing the application from the x86 directory. Also, I was hoping to grab some formatting tips.

```
if ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture -eq "64-bit") {
    # Download Application
    $source = "http://heartrate0001/x64/HeartRate.exe"
    $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($source)
    $destination = "$ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$filename"
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $webclient.DownloadFile($source,$destination)
    $patha = "C:\Program Files\ICU\HeartRate.exe"
    $pathb ="C:\Program Files (x86)\ICU\HeartRate.exe"
    $Folder1Path = 'C:\Program Files\ICU\HeartRate.exe'
    $Folder2Path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ICU\HeartRate.exe'
}

# Install Application
$process = Start-Process $destination -PassThru -Wait
$process.ExitCode

Write-Host $process.Exitcode

# Uninstall
if ((Test-Path -Path $Folder1Path) -eq "true") {
    {
        $Folder1Path = "C:\Program Files\ICU\HeartRate.exe"
        $arg1 = "-uninstall"
        & $Folder1Path $Arg1
    }
}

if ((Test-Path -Path $Folder2Path) -eq "true") {
    {
        $Folder2Path = "C:\Program Files\ICU\HeartRate.exe"
        $arg1 = "-uninstall"
        & $Folder2Path $Arg1
    }
} elseif ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture -eq "32-bit") {
    # Download Application
    $source = "http://heartrate0001/HeartRate.exe"
    $destination = "$ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$filename"
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $webclient.DownloadFile($source,$destination)

    # Install Application
    $process = Start-Process $destination -PassThru -Wait
    $process.ExitCode

    Write-Host $process.Exitcode

    # Uninstall
    $app = "C:\Program Files\ICU\HeartRate.exe"
    $arg1 = "-uninstall"
    & $app $Arg1
}
```

Comment: Your uninstall blocks have two sets of curly braces, I suspect this is making the contents a script block and therefore the code inside is not executing.

Comment: I'd suggest using environment variables > `"$env:ProgramFiles"` and `"${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}"`

Comment: Why are you installing just to uninstall the application again?

Comment: Its confusing I know, but we have a system agent that will communicate no matter what network the device lives on because it has an interface on each network.  For whatever reason the agent is stuck on our dev interface and wont communicate back to our production.  We need it to communicate back to get the new password to uninstall since the old admin doesn't know what he put as the password. Its goofy..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a script block inside your if statement. However, you never invoke that script block.

Change:

```
if ((Test-Path -Path $Folder2Path) -eq "true") {
    {
        $Folder2Path = "C:\Program Files\ICU\HeartRate.exe"
        $arg1 = "-uninstall"
        & $Folder2Path $Arg1
    }
}
```

to:

```
if ((Test-Path -Path $Folder2Path) -eq "true") {
    $Folder2Path = "C:\Program Files\ICU\HeartRate.exe"
    $arg1 = "-uninstall"
    & $Folder2Path $Arg1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to quickly.  Just for my own understanding,  how would I have invoked that script block if I didn't change it?

Comment: Using the ampersand character `&` @adam but it's superfluous and looks more like a typo than anything else.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is purely for a formatting example as requested by OP. Most of your work was redundant:

```
If ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture -eq '64-bit')
{
    $Source = 'http://heartrate0001/x64/HeartRate.exe'
    $Destination = "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\$([IO.Path]::GetFileName($Source))"
    # PSv3+
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Source -OutFile $Destination
    $x64 = "$env:ProgramFiles\ICU\HeartRate.exe"
    $x86 = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\ICU\HeartRate.exe"

    (Start-Process $Destination -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode

    If (Test-Path $x64) { & $x64 -uninstall }
    If (Test-Path $x86) { & $x86 -uninstall }
}
Else
{
    $Source = 'http://heartrate0001/HeartRate.exe'
    $Destination = "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\$([IO.Path]::GetFileName($Source))"
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Source -OutFile $Destination
    $x86 = "$env:ProgramFiles\ICU\HeartRate.exe"

    (Start-Process $Destination -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode

    If (Test-Path $x86) { & $x86 -uninstall }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I see how you were able to combine everything.  Thanks again.